# config settings for libguestfs to use software emulation

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

When I ran `libguestfs-test-tool` on an ESXI VM I got some errors which appear to get resolved when I use software emulation.

The man page for `libguestfs` says:

```
export LIBGUESTFS_BACKEND_SETTINGS=force_tcg
will force the direct and libvirt backends to use TCG (software emulation) instead of KVM (hardware accelerated virtualization).
```

However, our application has many services (run by different users) which make use of `libguestfs` tools, and it is painful to have to set this environment variable for each script and service. One alternative seems to be to rebuild the `libguestfs` library with `force_tcg` baked in, but I need to support platforms other than ESXI.

Is there one location I can specify this setting to force tcg? I would have thought that `/etc/libguestfs-tools.conf` might be the place, but that only allows a `read_only` attribute to be set.

Answer (score 1):

It's an environment variable; you can simply put it into everyone's environment, e.g. in a shell script in `/etc/profile.d`, or in the `Environment=` setting in services' systemd units.

Of course, for performance reasons you could instead [enable nested virtualization for this VM](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970) in its ESXi configuration. This would allow KVM to work inside the VM and provide better performance than software emulation.

Comment: The nested virtualization flag is already set in the ESXi 6.0 configuration. Still the errors from `libguestfs-test-tool` persist. And as I mentioned, I am looking for a configuration option as an alternative to environment variables.

Comment: It doesn't sound like nested virtualization is enabled for this VM. If it were, then KVM should be working. Try shutting down and then starting the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the kernel to version 4.16rc7 (unlreased as of now) seems to fix the issue. To summarize, it is a VMWare bug which is discussed in this thread https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2018-March/msg00152.html.